# Call Timer methods / modify properties from other threads in C++ Builder

Tags: c++, c++builder

I'm trying to achieve the following: to call methods or to modify properties of a TTimer timer which was created in the main thread, from another threads.

Code looks like the following:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
  Timer1->Interval = 5000;

  ht=(HANDLE)_beginthread(MyThread,4096,NULL);  // My Thread
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Timer1Timer(TObject *Sender)
{
  static int i = 0;

  i++;

  Edit1->Text = i;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------


void MyThread(void *threadparamlog)
{
  // .........  My code here

  Form1->Timer1->Enabled = true;

  // .......... My code here

  Form1->Timer1->Enabled = false;
}
```

Is it possible to call it like that, directly ? Or using of Synchronize is mandatory ? However, I got "E2268 Call to undefined function 'Synchronize'" when I tried to use it...
Please help.

Comment: `Synchronize` is a `static` (and also a non-`static`) function in [`System::Classes::TThread`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize). You could use (inherit from) `TThread` instead of using `_beginthread`. It usually makes life a lot easier in C++ Builder.

Comment: Hi Ted ! Thanks for your answer.  By "use and inherit from TThread" you mean to use the TThread class and create my threads from it ? Then Synchronize will work ?

Comment: Yes, but you _can_ use `Synchronize` on its own too since it's a static method. It's just that inheriting from `TThread` is often very convenient.

Comment: Are you using the classic compiler or the `clang` enhanced compiler?

Comment: Well, I don't know. Where should I look to find out ? I went to Project->Options->C++ Compiler but I did not see anything related to that.

Comment: Project\Options\C++ Compiler, then under C++ Compilers (WIN32 (if that's what you're using)), is 'classic' ticked in? I never use the 'classic' nowadays since it predates C++11. Like [so](https://imgur.com/a/Thlex5F)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have an older version of C++ Builder:  XE3 ... Options looks quite different from yours.... And yes, It's Win32 (only).

Comment: Ok, I hope I got something that works for you now.

Comment: @Misha4870 the clang-based compilers didn't start getting introduced until XE5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to call it like that, directly

It is not safe to do so. Always `Synchronize` when changing the state of VCL components being used in the main VCL thread from from a thread that is not the main VCL thread.

You can use the `static` `TThread::Synchronize` function from `<System.Classes.hpp>` with a lambda function that will be executed in the main VCL thread:

```
void MyThread(void *threadparamlog)
{
    // .........  Your code here

    TThread::Synchronize(TThread::CurrentThread, // or static_cast<TThread*>(nullptr)
        []{ // a lambda function
            // the code in here will be executed in the main VCL thread
            Form1->Timer1->Enabled = true;
        });

    // .......... Your code here

    TThread::Synchronize(TThread::CurrentThread, // or static_cast<TThread*>(nullptr)
        []{
            Form1->Timer1->Enabled = false;
        });
}
```

If your version of C++ Builder doesn't support lambdas, you could build a similar construct manually:

```
void __fastcall SetTimerEnabledValue(TTimer* timer, bool value)
{
    struct ManualLambda {
        TTimer* timer;
        bool    value;
        void __fastcall SetTimerValue() {
            // the code in here will be executed in the main VCL thread
            timer->Enabled = value;
        }
    };

    ManualLambda lambdaish;
    lambdaish.timer = timer;
    lambdaish.value = value;
    TThread::Synchronize(TThread::CurrentThread, // or static_cast<TThread*>(nullptr)
                         &lambdaish.SetTimerValue);
}
```

```
void MyThread(void *threadparamlog)
{
    // .........  Your code here

    SetTimerEnabledValue(Form1->Timer1, true);

    // .......... Your code here

    SetTimerEnabledValue(Form1->Timer1, false);
}
```

Comment: Thank You Ted. It worked ! It was the second variant which worked because of old version of my compiler (XE3) which do not support lambda functions. Again, Thanx !

Comment: @Misha4870 Great to hear! You're welcome!